# The key cannot be deleted. The key to be deleted is already deleted from an index by another concurrent session

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce-4

I have an issue where attempting to delete a row from a table generates this error.

> Error Code: 80004005
>
> Message: The key cannot be deleted. The key to be deleted is already deleted from an index by another concurrent session.
>
> Minor Err.: 25161
>
> Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>
> This may be related to a duplicate primary key entry in the database, yes I said duplicate primary key. This is a known issue with certain builds of Sql Compact. Does anyone know how I might be able to delete this row? There is no other session with the database nor is there a 'cascade on delete' for the index.
>
> File Version: 4.0.8876.1

[image]

Comment: What build (file version) of SQLCE are you using?

Comment: I encountered the same issue. The problem was definitely not caused by a lack of uniqueness. We use 64-bit version 4.0.8902.1 and entity framework version 6.1.3.

Answer (score 1):

After EF6 migration i have same issue. I used this tool for repair database: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeCmd/releases like that

```
SqlCeCmd40.exe -d "Data Source=C:\base.sdf" -e repairrecover
```

In my case it solve issue

Comment: For me a repair and an optimization solved same problem on CE db...